# How to efficiently calculate score = dot(a, LeakyReLU(x_i+y_j)) for each i, j in [N]?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I have to compute **score = dot(a, LeakyReLU(x_i+y_j))** for each i, j in [N], where a, x_i, y_j is the D-dimensional vecotr, and dot() is the dot-product that outputs a scalar value. So finally, I have to get NxN score.

In keras, I implemented as:

```
#given X (N x D), Y(N x D), A (D x 1)
X = tf.expand_dims(X, axis=1) #(N x 1 x D)
Y = tf.expand_dims(Y, axis=0) #(1 x N x D)
feature_sum = X+ Y #(N x N x D) broadcast automatically
dense = K.dot(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(feature_sum), A) # (N x N x 1)
```

The problem is that feature_sum is GPU-memory expensive, where N,D>1000. Then any other efficient implementation?

Comment: I don't believe so, you will need to have the `(N, N, D)` tensor in memory to compute the dot product.

Answer (score 0):

The dot product is a commutative operation with respect to the sum. Therefore:

```
dot(LRelu(X + Y), A) = dot(LRelu(X), A) + dot(LRelu(Y), A)
```

So, you can do:

```
dense_x = K.dot(LRelu(X), A)
dense_y = K.dot(LRelu(Y), A)

dense_x = tf.expand_dims(dense_x, axis=1)
dense_y = tf.expand_dims(dense_y, axis=0)

dense = dense_x + dense_y
```

In this way, all operations are done at most on `N x D` elements and you only have to store a maximum of `N x N` elements (assuming `N > D`).

---

### Quantitative comparisons. N=1000, D=500

```
def timeit(func):
    def run(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        out = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        print(f"Exec: {(end-start)*1000:.4f}ms")
        return out
    return run

@timeit
def fast(X, Y, A, N, D):
    X = X.reshape(N, 1, D)
    Y = Y.reshape(1, N, D)
    feature_sum = X + Y
    dense = feature_sum @ A
    return dense

@timeit
def fast(X, Y, A, N, D):
    dense_x = X @ A
    dense_y = Y @ A

    dense_x = dense_x.reshape(N, 1, 1)
    dense_y = dense_y.reshape(1, N, 1)

    dense = dense_x + dense_y

    return dense

def main():
    N = 1000
    D = 500

    X = np.random.rand(N, D)
    Y = np.random.rand(N, D)
    A = np.random.rand(D, 1)

    dense1 = slow(X, Y, A, N, D)
    dense2 = fast(X, Y, A, N, D)

    print("Same result: ", np.allclose(dense1, dense2))
```

Output:

```
Exec: 1547.9290ms # slow
Exec: 2.9860ms # fast
Same result: True
```